# php code to extract data month wise

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table containing several fields one of it is date field, I want to fetch all information of data related to current month.

how can I extract data on monthly basis based on application date.

```
 table name=user
 fields=name, email,phone,dob,bank account no,application date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very efficient but should do the job:

```
SELECT
    name, 
    email,
    phone,
    dob,
    bank_account_no
FROM
    user
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(application_date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: @Phpdeveloper np, glad i could help :)